# Does const reference prolong the life of a temporary object returned by a temporary object?

Tags: c++, lifetime, rvalue, temporary-objects, reference-binding

I know that const reference prolongs the life of a temporary locally. Now I am asking myself if this propriety can be extended on a chain of temporary objects, that is, if I can safely define:

```
std::string const& foo = aBar.getTemporaryObject1().getTemporaryObject2();
```

My feeling is that, since the the first method `aBar.getTemporaryObject1()` returns already a temporary object, the propriety doesn't hold for `aBar.getTemporaryObject2()`.

Comment: A temporary will be valid during the expression it appears in. The fact that it returns another temporary, doesn't change the semantics. You can still capture it.

Comment: @StoryTeller but this doesn't mean that the first object will also be guaranteed to be valid during the lifespan of the second, right?

Comment: No, of course not. If the second object contains a reference to the first, it'll be a dangling reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lifetime extension only applies when a reference is directly bound to that temporary.

For example, initializing another reference from that reference does not do another extension.

However,  in your code:

```
std::string const& foo = aBar.getTemporaryObject1().getTemporaryObject2();
```

You are directly binding `foo` to the return value of `getTemporaryObject2()` , assuming that is a function that returns by value.  It doesn't make a difference whether this was a member function of another temporary object or whatever.  So this code is OK.

The lifetime of the object returned by `getTemporaryObject1()` is not extended but that doesn't matter (unless `getTemporaryObject2`'s return value contains references or pointers to that object, or something, but since it is apparently a `std::string`, it couldn't).

Answer (score 3):

```
std::string const& foo = aBar.getTemporaryObject1().getTemporaryObject2();
```

is valid (`TemporaryObject2` is extended but not `TemporaryObject1`)

```
std::string const& foo = aBar.getTemporaryObject1().member;
```

is also valid  (`TemporaryObject1` is extended).

but

```
std::string const& foo = aBar.getTemporaryObject1().getReference();
```

is not valid: lifetime of `TemporaryObject1` is not extended.

Answer (score 0):

The title is misleading. You shouldn't return a reference to **local object** as stated in the title, but **temporary object** (return by value).

```
string & foo1()
{
  string tmp("hello");
  return tmp; 
}

string foo2()
{
  string tmp("hello");
  return tmp; 
}

void foo3()
{
  const string & r1 = foo1(); // crashes later.
  const string & r2 = foo2(); // Ok, object lives in scope of foo3.
}
```

the second call is nothing else than:

```
const string & r2 = string("hello");
```

As long as the functions return by value, the call-stack doesn't matter. The life-time of the last object will be extended to the life-time of the scope of it's reference.