# Lifetime of std::bitset::reference object created in std::bitset::operator[]?

Tags: c++, bitset

I have been looking at header file of [bitset](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-3.4/bitset-source.html) standard C++ library header. I found out that overloaded operator[] `operator[](size_t ndx)` (defined in class `bitset`) returns a temproray object of class `reference`.

```
reference
    operator[](size_t __position)
{ return reference(*this,__position); }
```

This overloaded operator encapsulates the concept of a single bit. An instance of this class is a proxy for an actual bit. It can be useful in expressions like

```
bitset<10> b;
b[2] = true;
```

The `reference` class has defined overloaded `=` operator member function so that above example can work:

```
 //For b[i] = __x;
 reference&
     operator=(bool __x)
 {
   if (__x)
     *_M_wp |= _Base::_S_maskbit(_M_bpos);
   else
     *_M_wp &= ~_Base::_S_maskbit(_M_bpos);
   return *this;
}
```

However, i am confused over this expression:

```
if (b[2]) {
    //Do something
}
```

The `b[2]` first returns a temporary object of class `reference` and then overloaded operator (`operator bool() const`) is called on that returned temporary object to convert it to `bool` data type.

```
// For __x = b[i];
operator bool() const
{ return (*(_M_wp) & _Base::_S_maskbit(_M_bpos)) != 0; }
```

If temporary objects (object having automatic storage class) are created on stacks, then calling an another function  (`operator bool() const`) shouldn't destroys the temporary object returned by the first function call (`reference` object returned by `reference operator[](size_t __position)`)?

What is the lifetime of temporary objects in C and C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [class.temporary#4](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#4), emphasized is mine.

> When an implementation introduces a temporary object of a class that has a non-trivial constructor ([class.ctor], [class.copy]), it shall ensure that a constructor is called for the temporary object. Similarly, the destructor shall be called for a temporary with a non-trivial destructor ([class.dtor]). **Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression ([intro.execution]) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.** This is true even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception. The value computations and side effects of destroying a temporary object are associated only with the full-expression, not with any specific subexpression.

That temporary object will be destroyed at the last step of that given expression.

In fact, C++ relies on it for this very common expression can be work correctly:

```
int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, t = 0;
int a = x + y + z + t;
```

Because `x+y` is a temporary, `x+y+z` is another temporary.

---

The lifetime of temporary will be shortened following rules in [class.temporary#5](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#5)

> There are three contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the full-expression. The first context is when a default constructor is called to initialize an element of an array with no corresponding initializer ([dcl.init]). The second context is when a copy constructor is called to copy an element of an array while the entire array is copied ([expr.prim.lambda], [class.copy]). In either case, if the constructor has one or more default arguments, the destruction of every temporary created in a default argument is sequenced before the construction of the next array element, if any.

and it will be prolonged following rule in [class.temporary#6](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6):

> The third context is when a reference is bound to a temporary.116 The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference except:
>
> - A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call ([expr.call]) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call.
> - The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement ([stmt.return]) is not extended; the temporary is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in the return statement.
> - A temporary bound to a reference in a new-initializer ([expr.new]) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the new-initializer.

The first context can be seen in this example:

```
struct bar {
    bar() { std::cout << __func__ << '\n'; }
    bar(const bar&) { std::cout << __func__ << "__\n"; }
    ~bar() { std::cout << __func__ << '\n'; }
};

struct foo {
    foo(const bar& b = bar()) { std::cout << __func__ << '\n'; }
};

int main() {
    foo f[] = {foo(), foo()};
}
```

Above program should output:

```
bar
foo
~bar
bar
foo
~bar
```

The second context will be added to C++17, from then this program:

```
struct bar {
    bar() { std::cout << __func__ << '\n'; }
    bar(const bar&) { std::cout << __func__ << "__\n"; }
    ~bar() { std::cout << __func__ << '\n'; }
};

struct foo {
    foo() {}
    foo(const foo&, const bar& b = bar()) { std::cout << __func__ << "__\n"; }
};

struct foox {
    foo f[2];
};

int main() {
    foox fx;
    foox yx = fx;
}
```

must output:

```
bar
foo__
~bar
bar
foo__
~bar
```

For the third context, you can find the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36982822/4115625), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19865679/4115625)

Comment: There is one exception to your answer - a temporary can be bound to a named constant reference variable and its lifetime is extended to the lifetime of the said variable.

Comment: @Leon actually, there're 3 contexts which the lifetime is difference, I added it here

Comment: @Danh can you elaborate more class.temporary#5 and class.temporary#6?

Comment: @abhiarora Updated per your need

Answer (score 1):

The condition in `if (b[2])` including the `operator bool()` is a single expression and temporaries are valid for the whole lifetime of an expression.